# Why would you assign to $$?

Tags: perl

`perldoc perl5150delta` says:

```
   $$ can be assigned to
       $$ was made read‐only in Perl 5.8.0.  But only sometimes: "local $$"
       would make it writable again.  Some CPAN modules were using "local $$"
       or XS code to bypass the read‐only check, so there is no reason to keep
       $$ read‐only.  (This change also allowed a bug to be fixed while
       maintaining backward compatibility.)
```

`$$` is the current process ID, why in the world would you assign to it?

Comment: Supporting the day sometime in the uncertain future when POSIX is updated to provide a `setpid()` call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only a couple (literally) places in CPAN where people want to assign to `$$`, and it's mostly for testing (I haven't understood `IPC::Messaging` yet). I don't like this feature, especially since there's a much better way to get the same effect. The Perl 5 Porters added this feature because they could and they would rather not make the couple of cases do a better job of testing. If you read the p5p thread, it's obvious that this feature wasn't driven by need.

I wrote about it in [Hide low-level details behind an interface](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1196).

However, I could be wrong on this because I'm not that good at the low-level black magic. I know there is a need to coordinate PIDs, but so far I think that `$$` isn't the only way to do that. If someone has a use case that they can explain to me, I'll update that post.

Answer (score 3):

`IPC::Messaging`, which provides sorta kinda Erlang-like messaging (not performance-wise, syntax-wise) does that to `$$` to replace it with an object which numifies to the original pid.  This is done to have a convenient reference to a "self-process" which one can call methods on (= send messages to).

Full disclosure: I am the author of the module.

Comment: I looked at this module, and I don't really understand what you need to do (although I know what you are doing). Does any of the stuff I say in http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1196 apply in your case? If not, I'd like to understand why and update my post to show that sometimes you might need to assign to $$. :)

Comment: brian, the module can spawn processes and send messages to them afterwards.  A message send looks like a method call on a var representing a process: `$proc1->message1(1,2,3);`.  Sometimes one wants to send message to the current process.  I chose to make `$$` an object so that the same syntax applies: `$$->messageBlah(42);`.  It is by no means a hard requirement; a global var or a function call like `this_proc()->messageBlah(42)` would work just fine.  But since `$$` already has a strong association with "this process", such syntactical cuteness seemed appropriate, in the module's context.

Answer (score -1):

If you were the syscall implemenation of a fork() like system call you would need to assign to the global one.

Comment: You mean if the kernel were written in Perl?

Comment: No, I mean if the syscall gateway were written in perl.

Comment: @Joshua: then why was it made read-only at one point? Seems to me like if something critical like `fork` stopped reporting the right PID that would make quite a mess of things...

Comment: @Heath - I assume that, in the code that implements `fork`, at some point after the fork you may need to modify the value of `$$`. Perl's built-in `fork` undoubtedly does this for you, but if your (XS) module calls the native-C `fork` rather than Perl's version, you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: @Chris Lutz But if you were in XS, you could muck with `$$` anyway (you would have access to `SvREADONLY_off`).  This change allows Perl code to muck with `$$`.

Comment: @Chas. - It's not that hard to throw in a few layers of indirection: Custom `fork`-like function written in C, wrapped (with no frills) with XS, called from your pure Perl library that now has to properly adjust `$$` after the function.